# Quartz blocking on Select for update

Tags: java, oracle, quartz-scheduler

I have big application where 4 nodes are using quartz to schedule jobs.

Very frequently I am getting mails from our DB team that

'SELECT * FROM QRTZ_LOCKS WHERE LOCK_NAME='TRIGGER_ACCESS' FOR UPDATE'

is blocking for 15-20 minutes. Sometimes hours.
And I see that my jobs are also stuck waiting for lock.

We are using Quartz 1.8.3 which is pretty old version. Here is Quartz setting I am using

```
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceName = DefaultQuartzScheduler
org.quartz.scheduler.instanceId = AUTO
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.export = false
org.quartz.scheduler.rmi.proxy = false
org.quartz.scheduler.wrapJobExecutionInUserTransaction = false

org.quartz.threadPool.class = org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool
org.quartz.threadPool.threadCount = 25
org.quartz.threadPool.threadPriority = 5
org.quartz.threadPool.threadsInheritContextClassLoaderOfInitializingThread = true

org.quartz.jobStore.misfireThreshold = 60000

org.quartz.jobStore.class=org.quartz.impl.jdbcjobstore.JobStoreCMT

org.quartz.jobStore.driverDelegateClass=com.xyx.abc.common.scheduler.impl.CDAJDBCDelegate
org.quartz.jobStore.useProperties=false
org.quartz.jobStore.tablePrefix=QRTZ_
org.quartz.jobStore.isClustered=true
org.quartz.jobStore.clusterCheckinInterval = 20000

# these 3 are required by customSchedulerFactory class
org.quartz.dataSource.myDS.connectionProvider.class=com.xyz.abc.common.scheduler.impl.CustomPoolingConnectionProvider
org.quartz.jobStore.dataSource=myDS
org.quartz.jobStore.nonManagedTXDataSource=myDS
```

I tried enabling debug logs for Quartz. But didn't get much from it.

Has anyone faced similar issue? How to make sure that 'Select for update' query is executing fast?

Comment: SELECT FOR UPDATE query locks rows in the QRTZ_LOCKS table so if there are concurrent SELECT FOR UPDATE queries on those same rows in that table then those concurrent queries are going to be waiting on the first SELECT FOR UPDATE query to release the lock on those rows either by commit-ing or making a rollback before executing.

Comment: Agree with @ivanzg. You issue is not with Quartz, looks like you have issue with locks on Database.

Comment: Has this been resolved?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably ignore these queries.

Many years ago I was on the other side of this issue.  I was the guy on the database team who found a long-running query and asked the Java developers to fix it.  I can't remember the details, but I remember there was a good explanation for why it worked this way and that there wasn't anything to fix.

The queries always showed up in performance reports when we sorted by `GV$SQL.ELAPSED_TIME` descending.  But on closer inspection we found that they didn't use any *important* resources.  They weren't using CPU, I/O, or any other precious resource.  It's one of those rare times when the `ELAPSED_TIME` column is misleading.

I learned to just ignore them and worry about other queries.